# R: string var like list menber name

Tags: r, list

in R list, I can set the list member name with

```
> l = list()
> l$a = 1:10
> l
$a
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

but, How I can set the list member name from a string varible ? like

```
> var_name = "a"
> l = list()
> l$var_name <- 1:10
> l
$var_name
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using `[[` instead of `$`?

```
> l[[var_name]] <- 1:10
> l
$a
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```